# Keeping divs straight in CSS

Tags: html, css

My editor just crashed and deleted all my work that I did. I'm trying to find a solution to make 3 div's look clean within a div -- centered, but not floated. I got it before, but I guess it was just a stroke of luck.

Now, the 1st div is too low, the 2nd div is centered, and the 3rd div is too low; I just want to get it horizontally centered and within in the page.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'abel';
  font-size: 100%;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

#title {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

#address {
  background-color: #ff9595;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav {
  background-color: #ffa327;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#midframe {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#packages {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25em;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

#package1 {
  float: left;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .24804em;
}

#midframe section img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
}

#reprints {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 25em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  clear: both;
}

#colorreprint {
  border: px solid red;
  float: left
}

#blackwhiterp {
  border: px solid red;
  float: right;
}

#footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  margin-top: 5em;
  clear: both;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
  #midframe {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #midframe section {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id=title><span id=hpdesign>HP</span> <span id=photographydesign>Photography</span></h1>
<h2 id=address>
  <p>7235-3 Franklin Blvd</p>
  <p>Sacramento, Ca 95823</p>
  <p>(916)424-5968</p>
</h2>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <span><li>Hours of Operation
                </li>
                <li>Mon-Sat 11AM - 7PM</li>
                <li>Sunday 11AM - 6PM</li></span>
    <span><li>Services</li>
                    <li>Portraits</li>
                    <li>Weddings</li>
                    <li>Graduations</li>
                    <li>Family</li>
                    <li>Commercials</li>
                    <li>Passports</li>
                    <li>Publicity</li>
                <li>Custom Printing</li>
                <li>Enlargements</li>
                    <li>Texture</li>
                    <li>Mounting</li>
                </span>

  </ul>
</nav>

<div id='midframe'>

  <section id='packages'><b><p>Standard Package Deals</p></b>


    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 1</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$18.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>1-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>1-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>8-wallets</tr>
    </div>

    <div id=package1><b><th>Package 2</th></b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$22.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>2-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>4-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>12-wallets</tr>
    </div>

    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 3</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$32.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>3-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>6-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>24-wallets</tr>
    </div>

    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 4</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$50.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>4-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>8-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>40-wallets</tr>
    </div>


    <b><p>Black & White, Brown Tone Packages</p></b>


    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 1</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$22.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>1-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>1-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>8-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 2</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$30.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>2-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>4-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>12-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 3</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$39.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>3-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>6-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>12-wallets</tr>
    </div>

    <div id=package1>
      <b><th>Package 4</th></b><br/>
      <tr>$56.99</tr><br/>
      <tr>4-8x10</tr><br/>
      <tr>8-5x7</tr><br/>
      <tr>40-wallets</tr>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section><img src="images/hp.jpg" width=500px></section>

  <section>
    <div id='reprints'><b><p>Reprint Options</p></b>

      <div id=colorreprint><strong><th>Color</th></strong>
        <br/>
        <tr>2- Wallets $1.00</tr><br/>
        <tr>10- Wallets $4.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>20- Wallets $7.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>30- Wallets $9.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>60- Wallets $14.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>3X5- $1.00</tr><br/>
        <tr>4X6- $1.25</tr><br/>
        <tr>5X7- $1.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>6X8- $3.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>8X10- $4.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>8X12- $5.99</tr><br/>

      </div>

      <div id=blackwhiterp><strong><th>Black & White, Brown Tone</th><br/></strong>
        <tr>2- Wallets $2.00</tr><br/>
        <tr>10- Wallets $6.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>20- Wallets $11.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>30- Wallets $14.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>60- Wallets $21.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>3X5- $1.50</tr><br/>
        <tr>4X6- $2.50</tr><br/>
        <tr>5X7- $2.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>8X10- $6.99</tr><br/>
        <tr>8X12- $7.99</tr><br/>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: What `div's` exactly are you talking about?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/colufidezi/edit?html,css,output Here is jsbin to your question. Please, always provide it, so people can help u faster.

Comment: I'm talking about the sections in the div "midframe"

Comment: Or just use StackOverflow's built-in Code Snippet for user-friendly troubleshooting and reproduction, we can easily copy the snippet to our answer and improve it from there.

Comment: @GONG Its actually preferable to use Code Snippets provided directly in the SO editor. See: [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Can you provide an image of what you are trying to do? I don't really understand what is wrong and what you want.

Comment: Do you get the result you're trying to achive if you declare `vertical-align: top;` to `#packages`?

Comment: FluffyKitten, I just want the packages, reprints, and photo in the middle to align all horizontally without having to float it left or right... UncaughtTypeError, that works for #packages, but it does not work for #reprints hanging out on the bottom right there... I had it working before! I was so happy! I used all simple code but now I just can't seem to achieve it

Comment: Just apply the same rule to `#reprints` then, or better apply the same rule to all nested `section` elements in `#midframe`, **e.g:** `#midframe section {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}`

Comment: What do you mean "aligned horizontally"? Have you tried running the snippet (in expanded mode) I created from your code? Maybe I misunderstood, but that looks like its doing what you describe. If you want them aligned *vertically*, then adding vertical-align: top; as @UncaughtTypeError suggested works.

Comment: Thank you UncaughtTypeError... that was really helpful, but I really wish I had known what I had done before to achieve that similar look. It's really frustrating. Another question, why wouldn't it work when I put it in the section itself, but it work when I put it in the media query? And also... WHY DO THE SECTIONS ALWAYS END UP ON WEIRD LOOKING POSITIONS AND HAVE TO BE ALIGNED LIKE THAT?! I DIDN'T WRITE THAT INTO THE CODE!

Comment: Thanks FluffyKitten, I'll research your post later, but I've gotta get some rest now that you've guys figured this out for me.

Comment: And yeah I meant aligned horizontally... I had it done up before, but I just couldn’t think of a way to do it again once I got to the step without using Vertical align.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:flex;` in the main div and then flex with a width in the children section.

Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ef60wbmg/

**HTML:**

```
<div id='midframe'>
  <section id='packages'>
    <b>
      <p>Standard Package Deals</p>
    </b>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 1</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$18.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>1-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>1-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>8-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 2</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$22.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>2-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>4-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>12-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 3</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$32.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>3-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>6-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>24-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 4</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$50.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>4-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>8-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>40-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <b>
      <p>Black & White, Brown Tone Packages</p>
    </b>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 1</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$22.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>1-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>1-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>8-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 2</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$30.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>2-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>4-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>12-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 3</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$39.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>3-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>6-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>12-wallets</tr>
    </div>
    <div id=package1>
      <b>
        <th>Package 4</th>
      </b>
      <br/>
      <tr>$56.99</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>4-8x10</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>8-5x7</tr>
      <br/>
      <tr>40-wallets</tr>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section><img src="images/hp.jpg" width=500px></section>
  <section>
    <div id='reprints'>
      <b>
        <p>Reprint Options</p>
      </b>
      <div id=colorreprint>
        <strong>
          <th>Color</th>
        </strong>
        <br/>
        <tr>2- Wallets $1.00</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>10- Wallets $4.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>20- Wallets $7.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>30- Wallets $9.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>60- Wallets $14.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>3X5- $1.00</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>4X6- $1.25</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>5X7- $1.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>6X8- $3.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>8X10- $4.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>8X12- $5.99</tr>
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div id=blackwhiterp>
        <strong>
          <th>Black & White, Brown Tone</th>
          <br/>
        </strong>
        <tr>2- Wallets $2.00</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>10- Wallets $6.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>20- Wallets $11.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>30- Wallets $14.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>60- Wallets $21.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>3X5- $1.50</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>4X6- $2.50</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>5X7- $2.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>8X10- $6.99</tr>
        <br/>
        <tr>8X12- $7.99</tr>
        <br/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#midframe {
  display:flex;
}
section {
    flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}
```